# How to remove a large file from git

Tags: git

A few commits ago, I added a large image to a git repo. A few commits later I delete the image  and used `git add -A`.

Is there a way to make git think as if that large file never existed?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite history from the commit where you added the big file. There are countless possibilities, including `git filter-branch` or `git rebase` or even `git cherry-pick` with some manual branch manipulation.

Some related answers:

- [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository) with `rebase` or `filter-branch`. This answer is rather a wiki :-)
- [pushing to gihub error using Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155248/pushing-to-gihub-error-using-rails/23156278#23156278) for a simple `filter-branch` solution